# Ask "yes" or "no" in flutter dialog?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, flutter-dialog

I want to ask user "Yes" or "No", to continue (or not) some action. I have code that shows alert, but don't know how to close automatically alert dialog after user have clicked one of the two buttons.

```
bool showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, String message) {
  bool returnValue = false;
  // set up the buttons
  Widget cancelButton = ElevatedButton(
    child: Text("Cancel"),
    onPressed: () { returnValue = false; },
  );
  Widget continueButton = ElevatedButton(
    child: Text("Continue"),
    onPressed: () { returnValue = true; },
  ); // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Do you want to continue?"),
    content: Text(message),
    actions: [
      cancelButton,
      continueButton,
    ],
  ); // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
  return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way will be retuning bool on `pop` imo.

```dart
Future<bool> showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, String message) async {
  // set up the buttons
  Widget cancelButton = ElevatedButton(
    child: Text("Cancel"),
    onPressed: () {
      // returnValue = false;
      Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
    },
  );
  Widget continueButton = ElevatedButton(
    child: Text("Continue"),
    onPressed: () {
      // returnValue = true;
      Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
    },
  ); // set up the AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Do you want to continue?"),
    content: Text(message),
    actions: [
      cancelButton,
      continueButton,
    ],
  ); // show the dialog
  final result = await showDialog<bool?>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
  return result ?? false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However I use go_router, not Navigator... Is it good to mix them in one project?

Comment: I think it is fine, because it is just used on dialog

Comment: OK. How I am suppose to read result of dialog, as this is Future<> ?? If you could write example of usage, it would be nice.

Comment: if the dialog dismissed by outside tap event it won't return any value, because it  didnt tap any of those two button, so I am making accepting null value, it the `result` is null, then it will return false

Comment: OK, I have managed it to work. Thanks again!

Comment: This code pops the underlying screen instead of the dialog?